# Проблема с очередностью выполнения плагинов Maven

Tags: java, maven

Я использую yuicompressor-maven-plugin для минификации файлов. Но когда я жму `package` в `target` попадают обработанные файлы, а вот в war-нике необработанные. Плагин привязан к фазе package и , видимо, обработка происходит после создания war.  Как с этим справиться?

pom.xml

```
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>

    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/air-datepicker-master/</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/sock.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/chat.css</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*min.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/resize.js</exclude>
                </excludes>

                <force>false</force>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Попробуйте в plugins добавить `<plugin><artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId><version>3.2.0</version></plugin>` **после** `yuicompressor-maven-plugin`.  https://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-plugin-execution-order-in-same-phase/

Comment: @Sergi, без изменений

Comment: а какая версия Maven?

Comment: @Sergi, 3. 3. 9

Comment: а что показывает mvn help:effective-pom - какой там порядок плагинов?

Comment: war plugin идет после компрессора

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99347/discussion-between-sergi-and-alex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку war плагин копирует ресурсы и сразу создает war, я не нашел способа вклиниться в этот процесс и хоть как-то автоматизировать. Но несложным решением будет просто создать war вручную:

```
cd target/<Project>
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\jar.exe" -cvf ROOT.war *
```

или с помощью exec-maven-plugin:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>target/<Project></workingDirectory>
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\jar.exe</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-cvf</argument>
                        <argument>ROOT.war</argument>
                        <argument>*</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```